# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have this method:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            callback.onFail(e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String body = response.body().string();


                    Response _response = gson.fromJson(body, Response.class);
                    callback.onCallBack(_response);



        }
    });
```

But I get an error message:
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: first you need to check your responce, check its in json form or not , https://jsonlint.com check here your json responce